# app not install in iphone4S

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I added a new device ID and downloaded the latest provisioning profile.

I created the project archive. The new profile works for all the old devices but does not work for the newly added device .

When I try to install the .ipa file using iTunes it stops in 3rd step(Determining app to sync).

**Following is the device log :**

```
finishing deferred symbolic links:
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]    /var/folders/X6/X62k2qceFk8k2XLGJwb-Ek+++TI/-Tmp-/IMA232qfBg/Payload/abc.app/CodeResources -> _CodeSignature/CodeResources
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  ]
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  + /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv -R=anchor apple generic and (certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)) /var/folders/X6/X62k2qceFk8k2XLGJwb-Ek+++TI/-Tmp-/IMA232qfBg/Payload/abc.app
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/var/folders/X6/X62k2qceFk8k2XLGJwb-Ek+++TI/-Tmp-/IMA232qfBg/Payload/abc.app: valid on disk
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  /var/folders/X6/X62k2qceFk8k2XLGJwb-Ek+++TI/-Tmp-/IMA232qfBg/Payload/abc.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  /var/folders/X6/X62k2qceFk8k2XLGJwb-Ek+++TI/-Tmp-/IMA232qfBg/Payload/abc.app: explicit requirement satisfied
1/18/13 3:49:54 PM  [0x0-0x65065].com.apple.Xcode[968]  ]
```

Can any one plz help me know what is Happening

Comment: are you sure latest provisioning profile has your new device Udid in it ?

Comment: do we have any way to check it

Comment: check your `deployment target` of your app and the `device version`. it might the problem of, your `device version` is lower than your `deployment target`.

Comment: deployment target is iOS4.2 and device is iphone 4S with iOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ipa related mobile provision profile is not installed in your new iPhone 4S. For that you have to drag and drop mobile provision profile into the itunes .